# How connect MongoDB to Heroku on Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

Why when i try to connect MongoDB to Heroku on Mongoose(in my node.js app) as written in docs(use:

```
`var uri = 'mongodb://dbuser:dbpass@host:port/dbname';  
mongoose.connect(uri);`
```

)errorlog offers me use `using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.`? Somebody, please, explain all way how to connect MogoDB to Heroku on node.js in 2017!! My app([git](https://github.com/IslamAlahovich/DB_Trening)) and errorlog:
[errorlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBnzi.jpg)

Comment: ofcourse in place on 'dbuser' and 'dbpass' i write my login and password on mlab, where i create my db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 'dbuser' and 'dbpass' you have to create a user for your database on mLab.(http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#users)
Don't use login credentials.

Comment: ахах, там же есть кнопка 'добавить пользователя', вот я долба*б. Thanks a lot!

Comment: but error again. 
`MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]`;
maybe you know decision?

Comment: i have tried your code and it works fine to connect to database whether to localhost or to mLab.

Comment: lol, i forgot `git add .` and  `git push heroku master`. Now it working, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possibly solution checklist
1) Ensure you create a `user` and `password` to your database in [Mongolab](https://mlab.com/databases/testing#users)

2) Visit [Reveal Config Vars](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/dockip-staging/settings) in your Heroku dashboard and map `MONGOLAB_URI` to your Mongolab database URI.

3) You can also test the URI in your Shell locally by running

```
mongo <host name>:port/database_name -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
```

Hope this helps you resolve your issue.